# How to get first element Peewee?

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee

There is query:

```
r = Products.select().where(Products.sku == article)
```

I tried to get first element like:

```
print (oldRow.first())
```

Also tried: `print (oldRow[0])`

I have got an error:

```
Error has occurred: Cannot convert b'7115.0000' to Decimal
```

Comment: Also I tried this: `return Products.select(Products.model).where(Products.sku == article).get()`

Comment: It returns me: `Error has occurred: 'Products' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be an instance of the same error you posted about (a similar question). Try this patch:

https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/cd07f4e01a1262166d8944736e11d0681fb76214

Also, Peewee model instances are not subscriptable. You should access the element using `oldRow.price` -- not `oldRow[0]`. The object returned by a query are model instances unless you explicitly tell peewee to return tuples/dicts/namedtuples.

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#BaseQuery.tuples